# Different ways to set custom DNS servers in OpenWRT 19.07.7

Tags: openwrt, dnsmasq

There are 4 different ways to set a custom DNS server in OpenWRT / LuCi, and it confuses me:

[image]
This is the method I'm currently using. It also was recommended online. Note that the LAN interface is supposed to be the WAN interface.

[image]
Not sure about this method.

[image]
I think this one would bypass the dnsmasq server.

[image]
Lastly, I read somewhere that this method could use DNS-over-HTTPS, but not sure.

I want to have ad blocking, so the local dnsmasq server should be used. I would also like to use DoH, as I'm already using Google DNS, though I read somewhere that the 2 aren't compatible. Again, not sure.

Could someone explain what the differences between the 4 are?

Also, on other routers I've set up, I was actually supposed to enter the router's IP to be served as DNS server. Is something similar required here, e.g. should I enter `192.168.1.1` in one of the other methods?